# How to create ABI with ricardian contract clauses using eosin-cpp

Tags: ricardian

I have eosin.cdt version 1.8.1 installed and i'm trying to create ABI file for my smart contract. I have placed my smartcontract.contracts.md and smartcontract.clauses.md files in ./ricardian subdirectory. I'm trying to compile it with:
eosio-cpp -abigen ./src/smartcontract.cpp -o ./smartcontract.wasm -R ricardian
but there is no effect and I'm still receiving:
Warning, action  does not have a ricardian contract
Can anyone help me with correct eosin-cpp parameters and/or proper file names / directories?

Answer (score 1):

Use cdt 1.7.x.  1.8 has known issues

See github issue here:
https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/issues/1174

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only problem is how to downgrade cdt 1.8.1 to 1.7.0